# Rails key value array to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this array I'm returning in Rails

```
[
  ["RETURNS FUEL SURCHARGE", "236.20"],
  ["RETURNS PRINT AND MAIL LABEL", "9.00"],
  ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 02/23/2013", "7.99"],
  ["SHIPPING CHARGE CORRECTION GROUND", "5471.01"],
  ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 03/02/2013", "-1.43"],
  ["RETURNS 3 UPS PICKUP ATTEMPTS", "187.50"],
  ["CHARGEBACK CHARGEBACK SURCHARGE", "24.00"],
  ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 03/16/2013", "-31.02"],
  ["SHIPPING CHARGE CORRECTION OVER MAXIMUM LENGTH", "50.00"],
  ["CHARGEBACK FUEL SURCHARGE", "2.44"]
]
```

I'm looking to place that info in table. I'm a little lost on best way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to iterate through your array and add a new table row for each entry in the array. So in your view (assuming this array is assigned to an @array variable in your controller) you could loop through your array like so:

Update: add array destructuring per tadman's suggestion

```
<table>
  <% @array.each do |description, amount| -%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= description %></td>
    <td><%= amount %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end -%>
</table>
```

Comment: It's also possible to label these like `do |description, amount|`.

Comment: If I wanted to sort the array by amount how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question - *If I wanted to sort the array by amount how would I go about doing that?*. yes you can do as below.

```
array = [["RETURNS FUEL SURCHARGE", "236.20"], ["RETURNS PRINT AND MAIL LABEL", "9.00"], ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 02/23/2013", "7.99"], ["SHIPPING CHARGE CORRECTION GROUND", "5471.01"], ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 03/02/2013", "-1.43"], ["RETURNS 3 UPS PICKUP ATTEMPTS", "187.50"], ["CHARGEBACK CHARGEBACK SURCHARGE", "24.00"], ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 03/16/2013", "-31.02"], ["SHIPPING CHARGE CORRECTION OVER MAXIMUM LENGTH", "50.00"], ["CHARGEBACK FUEL SURCHARGE", "2.44"]]
array.sort_by{|i| i[1].to_i}
# => [["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 03/16/2013", "-31.02"],
#     ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 03/02/2013", "-1.43"],
#     ["CHARGEBACK FUEL SURCHARGE", "2.44"],
#     ["BILLING ADJUSTMENT FOR W/E 02/23/2013", "7.99"],
#     ["RETURNS PRINT AND MAIL LABEL", "9.00"],
#     ["CHARGEBACK CHARGEBACK SURCHARGE", "24.00"],
#     ["SHIPPING CHARGE CORRECTION OVER MAXIMUM LENGTH", "50.00"],
#     ["RETURNS 3 UPS PICKUP ATTEMPTS", "187.50"],
#     ["RETURNS FUEL SURCHARGE", "236.20"],
#     ["SHIPPING CHARGE CORRECTION GROUND", "5471.01"]]
```